# setting ip address of database on different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I deployed a sample Rails app to a remote server with postgres hosted on the same server. The database.yml file was like this.

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: remotepg_production
  pool: 5
  host: localhost
  username: mrmann
  password: secret
```

Everything worked fine.   I then went into the database.yml file and replaced `host: localhost` with the ip address of a postgres database on another server `host: 178.XXX.XXX` like this

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: remotepg_production
  pool: 5
  host: 178.XXX.XXX.XXX        #ip address of server with other postgres database
  username: mrmann
  password: secret
```

When I restarted postgres on the server with the Rails app, the sample application now gave me the 'something went wrong' page for Rails.

The username and the password for the username are the same on both dbs.   Can you suggest what the problem might be?  Thanks

**Update**

These are the settings in pg_hba.conf on the server with the database that I want to connect to.

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Fake Rails app IP: 192.241.XXX.X

Fake Database IP: 192.34.XX.XXX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have access to the database logs? If your connection got as far as attempting to connect to the database, there should be some messages there. My WAG is that you need to add that IP to server's pg_hba.conf file and reload Postgres.
To be more clear, the IP to add to the server's pg_hba.conf is the IP that your application is connecting from, and you should also check the value of the database's `listen_addresses` setting. If the latter is not set to '*' or to the IP of your application, you'll need to change it in the postgresql.conf and restart the db cluster.

[edit, new information provided]

The line in your pg_hba.conf should be

```
host  all  all 192.241.XXX.X  md5
```

Reload (not restart) postgres (eg. `pg_ctl reload`) and then try connecting again. If it fails, find the db log and see what it shows. If there is no message, then it might be a firewall problem. If the latter is suspected, look for any rules relating to port 5432 in the output of `iptables -nvL`

Comment: I should have access to the database logs but I can't find where they are (can you help?). I'm assuming from your instructions that I need to add the IP of the database to the pg_hba.conf of the server hosting the rails app, or did you mean to add the IP of the server hosting the rails app to the pg_hba.conf of the server with the extra database?

Comment: The log locations I set up are always at: `select current_setting('data_directory')||'/'||current_setting('log_directory');`, maybe that path will lead you to your logs.

Comment: In `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf`, I just set the ip address of the server with the rails app as the listen_address. That's done now. However, when I tried to restart postgres it said `2013-07-25 17:10:35 UTC LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Cannot assign requested address
2013-07-25 17:10:35 UTC HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2013-07-25 17:10:35 UTC WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "178.XXX.XXX.X"
2013-07-25 17:10:35 UTC FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets`

Comment: In the pg_hba.conf file of the postgres database that I want to connect to, I also added  `host    remotepg_production            all             178.XXX.XXX.X        ident` to let the 'all' users from the server at that ip address connect to the remotepg_production but got the same error as last comment when trying to restart postgres

Comment: @Leahcim Try with `listen_addresses = '*'` and restart the db. Do you get the same errors?

Comment: I can restart the postgres database with that. Thanks. I did this in the pg_hba.conf file, and it told me that there was a syntax error with ip mask i.e. that `ident` wasn't correct.   `host remotepg_production all 178.XXX.XXX.X ident`  however, i'm not using `ident` as an ip mask but rather as a way to authenticate. Can you see the error I'm making?

Comment: @Leahcim Can you show the entries in your pg_hba.conf (change the IPs if you want)? Extract them manually or run the following: `egrep -v '^#|^$' pg_hba.conf`

Comment: I removed that line that I showed you in my previous comment, so now my pg_hba.conf is as the update to the OP shows. I also posted two ip addresses. Please let me know which should go where. thanks